# App in expo keeps refreshing and rebuilding randomly without any apparent trigger

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using Expo Client for my project. It was working fine until it started refreshing on its own and now it rebuilds without any reason. The toast with **Refreshing..** message is almost always visible. I'm using android phone with Windows computer.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found out somewhere that this problem has something to do with the hosted part of your project, and apparently my cPanel's php version was outdated. I updated it and everything's fine now.